# Amazon Product Advertising API: XXX is not a valid value for BrowseNodeId

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am using the Amazon product Advertising API to fetch the product categories. For US categories it is working.

But using browse nodes from different sites I get the following error:

```
"569604 is not a valid value for BrowseNodeId. Please change this value and retry your request."
```

I got the browse-nodes from the following site:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/index.html?BrowseNodeIDs.html

Where is the problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is not a C#- or .NET-specific issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an error that happens pretty regularly with the Products API, but not because the BrowseNodeId does not exist.  Rather, the API intermittently craps out and returns this error.  If you run it again, it will probably return the node correctly.

The way I have gotten around this limitation is to wrap the call in retry code.

Edit.

I tried running this BrowseNodeId, and indeed, it is invalid.  The BrowseNodeIds change regularly, and because this is a german browse node you may not be able to access it from the US.

However, according to this, your BrowseNode (Electronics, DE) should be available in the US:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/APPNDX_SearchIndexValues.html

You can test browse nodes at this url:

http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/browse/-/$N/

where $N is the browse node.

Comment: Test url was super helpful. My formerly good node was bad, and it redirected me to the replacement.